# Sinatra-Assetpack not serving js files

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino, sinatra-assetpack

This should be pretty easy, but it's simply not working. Running Padrino with sinatra-assetpack. All css files serve perfectly like this:

```
serve '/stylesheets', from: '/app/stylesheets'
css :shared, [
  '/stylesheets/reset.css',
  '/stylesheets/runemadsen.css'
]
```

But when trying to serve .js files, it doesn't work. I get a 404 in the script load:

```
serve '/javascripts', from: '/app/javascripts'
js :shared, [
  '/javascripts/jquery.js'
]
```

I really don't get it. It's exactly the same code. The files are there. Any tips?

Comment: Does sinatra provide a server error log that might be enlightening?

Comment: Nope, no Sinatra error. The js script tag shows up:
`<script src='/javascripts/jquery.js'></script>`
But the file is not there.

Comment: How about `ls -l` on the file?

Comment: Strange seems working on my app. I will try to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the issue, but can you get the basic approach working? The `serve '/javascripts', from: '/app/javascripts'` part is optional. From the [Readme](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack) with just the javascript:

```
require 'sinatra/assetpack'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
  register Sinatra::AssetPack

  assets {
    # The second parameter defines where the compressed version will be served.
    # (Note: that parameter is optional, AssetPack will figure it out.)
    js :app, '/js/app.js', [
      '/js/vendor/**/*.js',
      '/js/app/**/*.js'
    ]
  }
end
```

and for what is worth, my `assets` block looks like this:

```
  assets {
    js :main, [
      '/js/jquery.js',
      '/js/application.js',
    ]
```

With jquery located in `public/js` and application.coffee located in `app/js`. The script tag in my layout (haml) is `=js :main`.